# Открыть страницу XAML в TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Как правильно в `TabControl` открыть страницу WPF?

Comment: Что есть "правильно" в данном случае?

Comment: не так написал. "Как в TabControl открыть страницу WPF?"

Comment: Что такое «страница», по-вашему? [`Page`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: да, у меня просто русская Visual Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, для этого предназначен [`Frame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx). Попробуйте поместить `Page` во `Frame`.

Например:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="1">
        <Frame Source="/Page1.xaml"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="2">
        <Frame Source="/Page2.xaml"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: а можно поподробней как это сделать?

Comment: @Павел: смотрите обновление ответа